# Formula to subtract Month, Week, and Day

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have a list of days, and I am trying to create a formula that will take the days balance and tell me how many months, weeks, and days they are.

example: 28 days = 0 months, 4 weeks, 0 days

it's worth mentioning that months = 31 days, weeks = 7 days, and days are the leftover balance.

here is an example list:

8 
30  
16 
12 
12 
1 
12 
6 
1 
20 
6 
12 
14 
3 
53 
40 
19 
4 
3 
2 
2 
12 
14 
22 
91 
6 
62 
4 
17

any help appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
=INT(A1/31) & " months, " & INT((A1-INT(A1/31)*31)/7) & " weeks, " & A1 - INT(A1/31) * 31 - INT((A1-INT(A1/31)*31)/7)  * 7 & " days"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you an idea, without the actual formula, for the examples 91 and 53:

First you divide by 31:

```
91 DIV 31 = 2
53 DIV 31 = 1
```

You subtract that from the original number, and divide by 7:

```
91 - (2 * 31) = 29, 29 DIV 7 = 4
53 - (1 * 31) = 22, 22 DIV 7 = 3
```

You subtract that from the remaining number, in order to get the number of remaining days:

```
27 - (4 * 7) = 1
22 - (3 * 7) = 1
```

So:

```
91 : 2 months, 4 weeks and 1 day.
53 : 1 month,  3 weeks and 1 day.
```